# Big app.js file size (13 MB) for vuejs with laravel mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I am using vuejs with blade file in larvel 5.8. Means i am not using vue router but laravel view.
Recently i am facing a big problem that my public/js/app.js file size is about 13 MB!!
When i deploye to live, user face slowness when login!
I can't even alnalyze as i don't see any config file named webpack.config [shown here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)

> My app.js:

```
        import Vue from "vue"; 
    window.Vue = Vue;
    window.axios = require("axios");
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    require("promise.prototype.finally").shim();

    import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from "vform";
    window.Form = Form;

    Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError);
    Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError);

    Vue.component("pagination", require("laravel-vue-pagination"));

    //sweet alert 2

    import swal from "sweetalert2";
    window.swal = swal;
    const toast = swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: "top-end",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 15000
    });
    window.toast = toast;

    //vue lang

    import VueInternationalization from "vue-i18n";
    import Locale from "./vue-i18n-locales.generated";

    Vue.use(VueInternationalization);

    const lang = document.documentElement.lang.substr(0, 2);
    // or however you determine your current app locale

    const i18n = new VueInternationalization({
        locale: lang,
        messages: Locale
    });

    //vue lang end

    //https://hamed-ehtesham.github.io/pretty-checkbox-vue/#installation

    import PrettyCheckbox from "pretty-checkbox-vue";
    Vue.use(PrettyCheckbox);

    //vue autocomplete

    //ckeditor

    import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue";
    Vue.use(CKEditor);

    /**
     * Next, we will create a fresh Vue ap
     *
     *
     * plication instance and attach it to
     * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
     * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
     */

    // dash board

    Vue.component(
        "dashboard-site-employee-attendance-list",
        require("./components/dashboard/site/employeeAttendanceListComponent.vue")
    );
    Vue.component(
        "employee-attendance-master-component",
        require("./components/dashboard/site/latestAttendanceListComponent.vue")
    );
Vue.filter("round", function(value) {
    return parseFloat(value).toFixed(0);
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    i18n,
    components: {},

    methods: {},
    mounted() {
        console.log("d" + document.documentElement.lang.substr(0, 2));
    }
});
```

N>B: all my component are injected here (mentioned 2 only for precise)

> Blade File:

```
    @extends('default.admin.layouts.master')

@section('style')
    {!! Html::style('css/styles.css') !!}
@endsection

@section('content')

    <div class="container-fluid min_height_area">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="view-header">
                    <section class="content-header">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb">
                            <li>
                                <span class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <a href="{{route('admin')}}">{{ trans('translate.dashboard') }}</a></li>
                            <li class="active text-capitalize">{{ request()->route()->getName() }}</li>
                        </ol>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



            <employee-attendance-master-component
            >
            </employee-attendance-master-component>

    </div>

@endsection


@section('hscripts')


    <script>


        window.routes = {
            'attendance_list_by_shift_date': '{{ route('all-employee-attendance-list-by-shift-date') }}',
            'route_attendance_get_shift_list': '{{ route('site-employee-get-shift-list-for-employee') }}',
            'route_employee_attendance_edit': '{{ route('employee-attendance-edit') }}',
            'route_take_access_time': '{{ route('employee-attendance-take-access-time') }}',
            'route_log_by_date_and_username': '{{ route('edu-device-log-get-device-log-by-date-and-username') }}',
            'route_send_sms': '{{ route('site-employee-attendance-send-sms') }}',
            'route_report_date_shift': '{{ route('site-employee-attendance-report-date-and-shift') }}',
            'route_open_pdf_file': '{{ route('open-pdf-file-storage',['']) }}',
            'route_report_month_shift': '{{ route('site-employee-attendance-report-month-and-shift') }}',
            'route_emp_list': '{{ route('site-employee-get-simple-active-list') }}',
            'route_emp_yearly_report': '{{ route('site-employee-attendance-employee-wise-yearly-report') }}',
            'route_site_year_list': '{{ route('get-all-type-academic-year-list') }}',




            'route_user_list': '{{ route('site-user-get-site-user-by-user-type') }}',
            'route_user_data_update': '{{ route('site-user-data-update',['']) }}',
        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

> Webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

> My package.json file

[image]

EDit

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Add the [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) plugin and determine what's making it so big.

Comment: installed it now (shown in image dev portion). But how can i see it's output? where i can write config code as i don't see any webpack config related file but webpack.mix.js @Ohgodwhy

Comment: [There's a plugin specifically for Laravel](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/bundle-analyzer) that looks like it will get this done for you

Comment: Why i can't use webpack analyzer? Should i use default webpack instead of laravel mix or it is must with laravel?

Comment: You can. You can use `mix.webpackConfig({plugins: [ new BundleAnalyzer() ] })` in your `webpack.mix.js` file.

Comment: added analyzer image. plz tell me  now why it shows 12.8 MB --app.js@Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 7):

- Note that this is the development build, the production build size would be much smaller and it's what your users would have to download and run

```
npm run prod
```

- You can extract vendor assets into a separate file that would be cached longer

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .extract();
```

From the [Laravel Mix Docs](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/extract)

- You may also want to install [Import Cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost) extension for Visual Studio Code as it will show you the size of every ES6 module you import or require

And you can instruct `Webpack` to compile pages specific javascript and vue components so you can include them separately on blade view, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58122158/5581565)

Comment: What the benefit is from the separated file? As all files will be loaded at first visit! @Caddy

Comment: Vendor files will be cached, so when you change some of your Javascript code, the users won't have to download VueJS and other vendor assets again (they already have it cached on the browser) and so it'll be faster

Comment: And do you really use every component on every page?

Comment: Yes, as i am using blade file that is returned from controller action.@Caddy

Comment: And that blade file is the only one you have in all of your application?

Comment: No, there is a master layout file that is included with all blade file. see a simple blade file sample given in question. @Caddy

Comment: Wow! after running npm run prod now the app.js file is lowed by half! I mean 6.09 MB from 12.9 MB. How??

Comment: Because production build is minified and gzipped and no dev dependencies are compiled, just the bare minimum your application needs

Comment: Should the app.js file more smaller as it still says " /js/app.js  6.09 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app" ? But how can i do this? @Caddy

Comment: Updated my answer, follow the steps

Comment: Thanks. i will try and let you know if any other help needed. Thanks again for your help. @Caddy

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Please consider this series of articles about **Vue.js App Performance Optimization**, that really helped me a lot, in understanding lazy-loading,  shrinking the size and reducing the load time of my app.

1. [Lazy loading and code splitting in Vue.js](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-in-vue-js/)
2. [Vue.js Router Performance](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/vue-js-router-performance/)
3. [Lazy Loading Individual Vue Components and Prefetching](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/)

Main content :

- Introduction to performance optimization and lazy loading.
- Lazy loading routes and vendor bundle anti-pattern.
- Lazy loading Vuex modules
- Delivering good waiting experience and lazy loading individual components
- Lazy loading libs and finding smaller equivalents
- Performance-friendly usage of UI libraries
- Making use of Service Worker cache
- Prefetching
- ...